# Error caused by function that hasn't yet been run

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

So I'm writing a bill handling system. The data currently sits in a `Stack` structure that I've written.

I have this partially written function that writes out a report:

```
void GenerateReport(Bill* bill)
{
     PrintBillHeading(bill);
     //CallEntry* collatedEntries = CollapseCallStack(bill->callEntries);
//TODO
}
```

Which works fine as long as I leave the second line commented out. If I uncomment it I get a SIGSEGV fault within the `PrintBillHeading()` function where indicated below.

```
void PrintBillHeading(Bill* bill)
{
    printf("Big Brother Telecom\n");
    printf("Bill Date: %s\n\n",DateTimeToISOString(bill->date));
    printf("Contract Holder: %s %s\n", bill->title, bill->name);
    printf("Address:\n");
    char* addressSeg;
    char* addressCpy;
    strcpy(addressCpy,bill->address); //This line throws the SIGSEGV
    while ((addressSeg = strtok_r(addressCpy,";",&addressCpy)))
    {
        printf("%s\n\0",addressSeg);
    }
}
```

and for completeness here is my `CollapseCallStack()` function, this is uncomplete, entirely untested and probably doesn't work.

```
CallEntry* CollapseCallStack(Stack* calls)
{
    int size = calls->topIndex;
    CallEntry* collatedSet = malloc(sizeof(CallEntry) * size);
    CallEntry* poppedCall;
    int curIndex = 0;
    while (PopStack(calls,poppedCall))
    {
        bool found = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            CallEntry* arrItem = collatedSet + i * sizeof(CallEntry);
            if (StringEquals(arrItem->phoneNumber,poppedCall->phoneNumber))
            {
                found = true;
                arrItem->minutes += poppedCall->minutes;
            }
        }
        if (!found)
        {
            memcpy(collatedSet,poppedCall,sizeof(CallEntry)); //
        }
    }
}
```

And the `CallEntry` struct:

```
typedef struct{
    char* phoneNumber;
    int minutes;
    DateTime* callDateTime;
} CallEntry;
```

My question is this: how can a function that hasn't yet been called cause a SIGSEGV fault to be expressed earlier on in a program?

Once I've got past this, I can debug the `CollapseCallStack()` function myself, although if anyone sees any glaring problems I would appreciate a comment on that.

Comment: Please add the stacktrace from a debugger, e.g. `gdb`.

Comment: Where is the code that allocates memory for `addressCpy` so you can `strcpy` into it?

Comment: @ChrisTurner that may be the problem... I thought `strcpy` did that itself... It seems to work with the second function call commented out though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In function `PrintBillHeading()`, the statement `strcpy(addressCpy,bill->address)` uses the value of an uninitialized variable `addressCpy`. This is undefined behavior. Undefined behavior means that the program may crash in any random place. If the program contains undefined behavior *the entire program is invalid*.

Comment: Yep, adding `addressCpy = malloc(200)` worked... Thanks!

Comment: @Persistence That won't work if `bill->address` is longer than 199 characters...it would be better to use `strlen(bill->address)+1` to ensure you allocate enough space. Or use `strdup` which does the `malloc` and `strcpy` in one function call

Comment: @Chris Turner Note that `strdup` is not part of the C standard. If you need to write portable code, you should not use that function.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the [correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54200917/9658875) by AlexP, I'd like to point out another (lurking) undefined behaviour:

```
void GenerateReport(Bill* bill)
{
     PrintBillHeading(bill);
     CallEntry* collatedEntries = CollapseCallStack(bill->callEntries);
//TODO
}
```

Now, `CollapseCallStack` in your current implementation **does not return anything**. It will still be called, and actually something will be assigned to your `collatedEntries` pointer upon your initialization of it.

The problem is that when `CollapseCallStack` is called, memory for the return value is being allocated, but it never gets assigned a meaningful value, since the return statement is missing. So, essentially your `collatedEntries` pointer will be initialized with a random garbage value, and if you'd try to dereference it, it would cause UB.